# Empty navigation bar appearing in subview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying display a `UITableView` within a larger `UIView` in an iPad app, mainly because the data is pretty sparse and I'd like to have the table be a smaller area over a background image, rather than taking up the whole screen.  The parent `UIViewController` is correctly set as the table data source and delegate, and the table looks/functions like it should.  The whole view is embedded in a navigation controller; the overall UIView shows a navigation bar, as it should, that I can configure normally.

The problem is the `UITableView` subview *also* shows blank space at the top for a navigation bar--empty space above the first cell--and I can't figure out how to get rid of it.  I know the space is related to the navigation controller, because when I delete the embed link in the storyboard, the space goes away.  The table view doesn't present a UINavigationBar property or any other navigation-related properties that I can try to nullify.

I would post a screen shot but I don't have the rep yet.

Can anyone explain where the space is coming from and how to nix it?

Comment: UITableView* myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];

Comment: Are you saying that I need to instantiate the UITableView programmatically instead of from the storyboard?  Why would that make a difference?

Comment: Oh sorry henry95 , I never work with storyboards / nibs / xibs and all of those , I always do everything programmatically so i donno how to help u with IB , but i would suggest to try to do it programatically

Comment: Beginning to think you're right about that.  Seems like the storyboard never quite does exactly what I need it to, so I end up learning the code for everything anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the answer is related to the Top Layout Guide for the view, but I can't diagnose the specific problem.

Here's a workaround from the storyboard: Insert a `UIView` in the scene, then drag the `UITableView` into it as a subview.  Check the box for the new UIView's "Clip Subviews" in the attribute window, and then use it as a mask, basically, to cover the undesired top margin of the table view.  It works and doesn't require any coding, but there has to be a better way.